# How to change an element variable within a function

Tags: javascript, function, shopify, element, flexslider

I'm working with the woothemes flexslider on Shopify and I'm looking at a specific function that changes the slideshow image when a product variant is selected. Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to change an element variable within the function as if it were a local variable. The function calls on the `element.flexslider(index)`, but I'd also like it to change the variable move to 1 for that specific function.

I've tried setting a local variable within the function block by adding the line `var move = 1`, but that didn't change anything. I tried changing the variable in the brackets where the flexslider index is referenced by changing `$element.flexslider(index);` to `$element.flexslider({index; move: 1})`. That didn't work either. I'm fairly new to working with Javascript so I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
$element.flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  directionNav: true,
  animationLoop: true,
  move: 2,
  prevText: "",
  nextText: "",
  slideshow: false,
  sync: "#carousel"
});

events
  .on("variantchange:image", select);

function select(id) {

  var slides = $element.find("[data-image-id]");
  var slide = slides.filter("[data-image-id=" + id + "]");
  var index = slides.index(slide);

  $element.flexslider(index);

};
```

My desired outcome is for the function to set the variable flexslider.move to 1 for the duration of the function, in the same way a local variable would be function-specific. When the function is complete, the page will return to using the previously defined value for flexslider.move (in this case, the value is 2).

Right now, the function is just using the previously defined variable and I don't know how to introduce a variable change for the function.

Comment: The duration of the function is essentially zero. If your goal is to change the `move` parameter to 1, you need to re-run the initial setup call and use 1 instead of 2.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered how fast the function is. The issue is that I need the parameter to be 2 because other functions call on it and I need those functions to use the value 2. But if this particular function is essentially happening instantaneously then maybe this isn't the right lead for the solution I'm trying to implement. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah; your entire question is about the solution you're trying to implement; try describing what the problem is that you're trying to solve.,

Comment: JL I know you are new here, but it looks like you are new to Javascript as well. I would start with https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/. They already have a callback API so you don't need to set up a new event.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll look into that. Thank you